# Adfs 3.0 for asp.net authentication

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, adfs, adfs3.0

I am trying to set up ADFS 3.0 to work with an ASP.NET MVC application in Visual Studio 2013. I was wondering if I needed to get a certificate from our ADFS administrator and import it into IIS where the MVC app runs in order for the authentication to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are encrypting the claim, you don't need certificates.

And anyway, the certificate would be in the certificate store, not in IIS.

The information your RP needs is in the ADFS metadata.

Your IIS may have a certificate for SSL but that is specific to your IIS - nothing to do with ADFS certificates.